# Condensing similar IF statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I know there has to be a better way than this:

```
if (mon_open_close_hours=='12:00-12:00'){
    mon_open_close_hours='24hrs';
}
if (tue_open_close_hours=='12:00-12:00'){
    tue_open_close_hours='24hrs';
}
if (wed_open_close_hours=='12:00-12:00'){
    wed_open_close_hours='24hrs';
}
if (thu_open_close_hours=='12:00-12:00'){
    thu_open_close_hours='24hrs';
}
if (fri_open_close_hours=='12:00-12:00'){
    fri_open_close_hours='24hrs';
}
if (sat_open_close_hours=='12:00-12:00'){
    sat_open_close_hours=['24hrs'];
}
if (sun_open_close_hours=='12:00-12:00'){
    sun_open_close_hours=['24hrs'];
}
```

Is there a way to condense this somehow?

I've tried this, but it returns `'12:00-12:00'` for everything

```
var $variables = [mon_open_close_hours,tue_open_close_hours,wed_open_close_hours,thu_open_close_hours,fri_open_close_hours,sat_open_close_hours,sun_open_close_hours];
     $variables.map(function(val) {
        if(val=='12:00-12:00'){
            val=['24hrs'];
        }
    })
```

Comment: Show a little more code. How do you use it? In general, it looks like you need to store open-close hours in an array of weekdays, not in separate variables.

Comment: The hours can array of strings that consists of actual hours (`[11:00-3:00]`) or they can be empty (`[]`) or they can be (`'24hrs'`). That's the reason for all these tests.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Added one thing I've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have already said, it is better to store open-close hours in an array of weekdays, not in separate variables. In this case, you will be able to operate with them using for-loops.

However, if we talk specifically about your case, then you use `Array.prototype.map` incorrectly.
Mapping function should **return** value, reassigning the reference to its argument in a local scope won't affect anything.
Also, `map` does not change the original array, it returns a new one, so you need to assign this result to a new variable or to the original one.

Use this:

```js
var openCloseHours = [
  "09:00-15:00", 
  "09:00-18:00", 
  "09:00-18:00", 
  "09:00-18:00", 
  "09:00-18:00", 
  "12:00-12:00", 
  "12:00-12:00"
];

openCloseHours = openCloseHours.map(function(val) {
  if (val == '12:00-12:00'){
    return ['24hrs'];
  }

  return val;
});

console.log(openCloseHours);
```

Comment: This returns `'12:00-12:00'` for every variable now.

Comment: @jonmrich No, it doesn't :) I have updated my answer with working code snippet which updates result with `["24hrs"]` for the last two days in a week.

Comment: I think the issue is that my `openCloseHours` are all strings in arrays, but I'm not sure how to get those out either.

Comment: That is, if I `console.log` right after `.map` line, I get `["12:00-12:00"]` 7 times

Comment: @jonmrich your format is unclear. Why do you have an array with one string?

Comment: @jonmrich, This answer addresses various aspects and I think it is the most suitable one. If you don't think so, then the question needs to be updated with more info in order to get exactly what you want.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Thank you. Took me a bit to figure out, but you suggestion to refactor everything and store as an array was the way to go. Once I had that formatted correctly, it all went smoothly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you truly want to improve it, you'd have to change the way you store and process data. This might require changes to the way your DOM is used, and how you interact with your backend. But it is certainly better than having 7 different variables for each day.

```js
var open_close_hours = {};
var days = ["mon","tue","wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"];

// Some code that sets the properties.
// ...

// Conditions.

days.forEach(function(day){
  if(open_close_hours[day] == '12:00-12:00') {
    open_close_hours[day] = ['24hrs'];
  }
});
```

Comment: Seems like the best answer to me so far (if it works) - doesn't use `eval` or `map` - `forEach` sits better with me.

Comment: @EdmundReed I agree with you that this data structure is better. But what's the problem with `map`?